# Bibdesk: TEX preview generation failed

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-chicago, bibdesk

#### Original post:

I use Bibdesk configured for `biblatex` and have been doing so for years. Today, for some reason, I am not able to generate TEX previews in Bibdesk as I have always been able to do, and my `.bib` files are not functioning properly when I run LaTeX (pdflatexmk) on my docs with bibliography material. I know the two must be related, but I'm scratching my head as to why, without any changes on my part, things are not working suddenly. Worked yesterday, but not today.

#### Update (same issue, new machine):

I have just set up BibDesk on a new machine (M2 MacBook Pro, Ventura 13.4.1), and am having the same problem as before. I set up the Tex Preview preferences exactly as I had them on my previous machine, but I am getting the error message:

[image]

This is the error log output:

```
***** WARNING: You are using a non-standard BibTeX style *****
The style "biblatex" may require additional \usepackage commands to function correctly.

---------- TeX log file ----------
File: "/var/folders/03/6f69kxnx2rb403pd3f8d_dh80000gn/T/bibdesk.XkIBLl/bibpreview/bibpreview.log"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.7.13)  17 JUL 2023 10:42
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**bibpreview
(./bibpreview.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex
/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/biblatex-chicago
.sty
Package: biblatex-chicago 2022/07/02 v 3.18 biblatex style
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count193
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2022-05-17 v2.50 Cross-referencing by name of section
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
)))
\c@section@level=\count194
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty (/usr/loc
al/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count195
\decimalpart=\count196
)
Package: xstring 2023/01/14 v1.85 String manipulations (CT)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2023/03/05 v3.19 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count197
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count198
\c@listtotal=\count199
\c@listcount=\count266
\c@liststart=\count267
\c@liststop=\count268
\c@citecount=\count269
\c@citetotal=\count270
\c@multicitecount=\count271
\c@multicitetotal=\count272
\c@instcount=\count273
\c@maxnames=\count274
\c@minnames=\count275
\c@maxitems=\count276
\c@minitems=\count277
\c@citecounter=\count278
\c@maxcitecounter=\count279
\c@savedcitecounter=\count280
\c@uniquelist=\count281
\c@uniquename=\count282
\c@refsection=\count283
\c@refsegment=\count284
\c@maxextratitle=\count285
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count286
\c@maxextraname=\count287
\c@maxextradate=\count288
\c@maxextraalpha=\count289
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count290
\c@highnamepenalty=\count291
\c@lownamepenalty=\count292
\c@maxparens=\count293
\c@parenlevel=\count294
\blx@tempcnta=\count295
\blx@tempcntb=\count296
\blx@tempcntc=\count297
\c@blx@maxsection=\count298
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count299
\blx@notetype=\count300
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count301
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count302
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count303
\blx@sectionciteorderinternal@0=\count304
\blx@entrysetcounter=\count305
\blx@biblioinstance=\count306
\labelnumberwidth=\skip50
\labelalphawidth=\skip51
\biblabelsep=\skip52
\bibitemsep=\skip53
\bibnamesep=\skip54
\bibinitsep=\skip55
\bibparsep=\skip56
\bibhang=\skip57
\blx@bcfin=\read2
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\blx@langwohyphens=\language87
\c@mincomprange=\count307
\c@maxcomprange=\count308
\c@mincompwidth=\count309
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def
File: blx-dm.def 2023/03/05 v3.19 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'chicago-notes.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count310
\c@savedafterword=\count311
\c@annotator=\count312
\c@savedannotator=\count313
\c@author=\count314
\c@savedauthor=\count315
\c@bookauthor=\count316
\c@savedbookauthor=\count317
\c@commentator=\count318
\c@savedcommentator=\count319
\c@editor=\count320
\c@savededitor=\count321
\c@editora=\count322
\c@savededitora=\count323
\c@editorb=\count324
\c@savededitorb=\count325
\c@editorc=\count326
\c@savededitorc=\count327
\c@foreword=\count328
\c@savedforeword=\count329
\c@holder=\count330
\c@savedholder=\count331
\c@introduction=\count332
\c@savedintroduction=\count333
\c@namea=\count334
\c@savednamea=\count335
\c@nameb=\count336
\c@savednameb=\count337
\c@namec=\count338
\c@savednamec=\count339
\c@translator=\count340
\c@savedtranslator=\count341
\c@shortauthor=\count342
\c@savedshortauthor=\count343
\c@shorteditor=\count344
\c@savedshorteditor=\count345
\c@labelname=\count346
\c@savedlabelname=\count347
\c@institution=\count348
\c@savedinstitution=\count349
\c@lista=\count350
\c@savedlista=\count351
\c@listb=\count352
\c@savedlistb=\count353
\c@listc=\count354
\c@savedlistc=\count355
\c@listd=\count356
\c@savedlistd=\count357
\c@liste=\count358
\c@savedliste=\count359
\c@listf=\count360
\c@savedlistf=\count361
\c@location=\count362
\c@savedlocation=\count363
\c@organization=\count364
\c@savedorganization=\count365
\c@origlocation=\count366
\c@savedoriglocation=\count367
\c@origpublisher=\count368
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count369
\c@publisher=\count370
\c@savedpublisher=\count371
\c@language=\count372
\c@savedlanguage=\count373
\c@origlanguage=\count374
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count375
\c@pageref=\count376
\c@savedpageref=\count377
\shorthandwidth=\skip58
\shortjournalwidth=\skip59
\shortserieswidth=\skip60
\shorttitlewidth=\skip61
\shortauthorwidth=\skip62
\shorteditorwidth=\skip63
\locallabelnumberwidth=\skip64
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip65
\localshorthandwidth=\skip66
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip67
\localshortserieswidth=\skip68
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip69
\localshortauthorwidth=\skip70
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip71
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2023/03/05 v3.19 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2023/03/05 v3.19 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count378
\c@textcitetotal=\count379
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count380
\c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count381
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count382
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count383
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count384
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count385
\biburlbigskip=\muskip17
\biburlnumskip=\muskip18
\biburlucskip=\muskip19
\biburllcskip=\muskip20
\c@smartand=\count386
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'chicago-notes'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'chicago-notes.bbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.bb
x
File: chicago-notes.bbx 2022/11/17 v 3.18b biblatex bibliography style
\lositemsep=\skip72
Package biblatex Info: Delimiter 'revsdnamedelim' in context '' already defined
, overwriting.
\cms@tempcnta=\count387
\cms@tempcntb=\count388
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count389
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count390
\c@cms@reviewcount=\count391
\c@cms@currentnote=\count392
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'chicago-notes'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'chicago-notes.cbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.cb
x
File: chicago-notes.cbx 2022/11/17 v 3.18b biblatex citation style
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footfullcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\fullcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\citeincitef'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\citeauthor'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
\c@cms@punct=\count393
Package biblatex Info: Delimiter 'dateeradelim' in context '' already defined, 
overwriting.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
)
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Document encoding is UTF8 ....
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2023-02-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-01-16 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count394
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
))
Package biblatex Info: ... and expl3
(biblatex)             2023-02-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(biblatex)             is new enough (at least 2020/04/06),
(biblatex)             setting 'casechanger=expl3'.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty (/usr
/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2023-02-02 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: blx-case-expl3 2023/03/05 v3.19 expl3 case changing code for biblatex
)))
\@quotelevel=\count395
\@quotereset=\count396
No file bibpreview.aux.
\openout1 = `bibpreview.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 21.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 21.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english' -> 'cms-american'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'cms-american.lbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/cms-american.lbx
File: cms-american.lbx 2022/07/02 v 3.18 biblatex localization
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'american'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'american.lbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
File: american.lbx 2023/03/05 v3.19 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2023/03/05 v3.19 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2023/03/05 v3.19 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
))
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout3 = `bibpreview.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'bibpreview.bbl' not found.
No file bibpreview.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 21.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 21.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'fowl:philippians' undefined on input line 23.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 24.

(./bibpreview.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                bibpreview
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'bibpreview.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `bibpreview.run.xml'.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11136 strings out of 476025
 225964 string characters out of 5790017
 1850388 words of memory out of 5000000
 31558 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 512287 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 85i,1n,90p,679b,3950s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)



---------- BibTeX log file -------
File: "/var/folders/03/6f69kxnx2rb403pd3f8d_dh80000gn/T/bibdesk.XkIBLl/bibpreview/bibpreview.blg"
(null)

---------- BibDesk info ----------
<BDSKTeXTask: 0x600000bdce80> {
ivars:
    delegate = "<BDSKPreviewer: 0x600002b5a700>"
    file name = "bibpreview"
    template = "/Users/roy/Library/Application Support/BibDesk/previewtemplate.tex"
    TeX file = "/var/folders/03/6f69kxnx2rb403pd3f8d_dh80000gn/T/bibdesk.XkIBLl/bibpreview/bibpreview.tex"
    BibTeX file = "/var/folders/03/6f69kxnx2rb403pd3f8d_dh80000gn/T/bibdesk.XkIBLl/bibpreview/bibpreview.bib"
    TeX binary path = /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
    BibTeX binary path = /Library/TeX/texbin/biber
    Encoding = "Western (ASCII)"
    BibTeX style = "biblatex"
    Helper files = (
)

environment:
    SHELL = "/bin/zsh"
    BIBINPUTS = "(null)"
    BSTINPUTS = "(null)"
    TEXINPUTS = "(null)"
    TEXCONFIG = "(null)"
    TEXMFCONFIG = "(null)"
    PATH = "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" }
```

Here are my current TEX Preview settings:

[image]

Here is my TEX template encoding:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}
\textwidth = 6.5in
\voffset = -105pt
\hoffset = -120pt
\renewcommand{\refname}{}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{<<File>>.bib} % you have to add ``.bib'' here because,
                              % for some reason, it won't find the
                              % file without it

% The following command is provided for LaTeX2RTF compatibility with amslatex.
\newif\iflatextortf
\iflatextortf
\providecommand{\bysame}{\_\_\_\_\_}
\fi

\begin{document}

\nocite{<<CiteKeys>>}
\printbibliography[heading=none] % I don't want a heading on my previews

\end{document}
\begin{document}
\[\]
\end{document}
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated. I'm baffled...again.

Comment: Did you try restarting your computer this time?

Comment: Or just clean out all the generated files?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both of those.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the log, you've either not run `biber` or `fowl:philippians` wasn't defined when you did. There's no error there. Compilation is successful. A reference is undefined, which is perfectly normal. Try running a complete compilation cycle by hand i.e. without any wrapper. I don't know how Bibdesk works, but it is at least odd you're using ASCII encoding. Certainly Biblatex detects UTF8 for your `.tex` file. If you still have trouble with a basic run (i.e. no `pdflatexmk` or Bibdesk), post a minimal non-working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Xcode. Restarted. Resolved.

Comment: For an explanation of why this worked, see [Why exactly does Biber need Command Line Tools?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/694749).